# Why 2 linux machine behave differently with command of the same syntax?

Tags: bash, shell, find, wildcards

I am using 2 machine , which is both *Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 2)*
 ( I check it in /etc/*-release ).

I checked they are using the same default shell by `ps -p $$`, which is bash.

I tried to execute a find command with wildcard pattern:
find path -name pattern -type f -ctime +3

and the pattern contain * character as wildcard.

The first machine seems to expanded the wildcard character and causing error:

```
find /home/primbat/testing -name sftp_bcs_report_*.log -type f -ctime +7
find: paths must precede expression
```

and I need to either make the pattern in between 2 delimited qoute, e.g: `\"sftp_bcs_report_*.log\"` or using `set -f` in the script to suppress wildcard expansion.

Which in the other machine, it have no such problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Just a note: instead of running find, echo the command line you are trying to run, i.e., run `echo find /home/primbat/testing -name sftp_bcs_report_*.log -type f -ctime +7`. It is clear that your shell is expanding the wildcard and, as you have two or more files matching the wildcard, the second one gets caught by `find` as an out-of-place path parameter.
Please note that you're lucky you have *more than one* file under that wildcard in the current directory, otherwise `find` would just accept the expanded wildcard *silently*!

Comment: Always put filenames in quotes.

Answer (score 13):

By default, shells expand wildcards if a file matches them but keep unexpanded without match. For example, if you run `touch /tmp/111; touch /tmp/11*` this will create and then update mtime on /tmp/111, but if /tmp is empty but you call `touch /tmp/11*` you will get file named "11*" in /tmp.

This is rather weird feature of shells. Sometimes proper expanding isn't possible without special hacks as intermediate function. Most current shells invent special options for typical cases; e.g. "shopt -s failglob" in bash rejects it from running any command where wildcard match fails.

One shall rely on find's wildcard expanding, so such pattern shall be quoted against expansion in shell:

```
find /home/primbat/testing -name 'sftp_bcs_report_*.log' -type f -ctime +7
```

(note single quotes). With zero or one file, it works, but with two or more files you get broken command syntax and it complains - this is what is said by colleague **Arcege**. Your "set -f" disables expansion totally - well, it is good measure for diagnostics but can give underwater rakes for a future moving. Quotes are simpler:)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like there is no file matching `sftp_bcs_report_*.log` in the starting directory on the second machine and more than one such file on the first server.  For using `find`, patterns should always be quoted.